# How to install verse package?

Tags: packages, installing, verse

How can I install the `verse` package? I did not find it in my Ubuntu 10.1. Through a Google search I went to:

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/verse

and followed the instructions. It gave me the following error:

```
(./verse.ins
*** Generating the LaTeX2e package files ***

Generating file(s) ./verse.sty 
! Cannot find file verse.dtx.
\readsource ...ot find file \uptospace #1 \qStop }
                                                  \else \processedLines \z@ ...
l.56 ...e{\file{verse.sty}{\from{verse.dtx}{usc}}}

? ^C! Interruption.
\readsource ...t \refusedfiles \empty \csname b@#1
                                                  \endcsname \Name \let {b@#...
l.56 ...e{\file{verse.sty}{\from{verse.dtx}{usc}}}

?
```

Comment: What version of LaTeX are you running? TeX Live or MiKTeX? Each of these have a package manager that you could try in order to simplify the installation of packages.

Comment: aku-desktop:~$ latex - version
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)

Comment: Then consider reading this: [tlmgr - The TeX Live Manager](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html). I would suggest trying `tlmgr install verse`.

Comment: The error message is very clear. It says `Cannot find file verse.dtx.`. So download `verse.dtx` too if you want install the package manually.

Comment: if aku is running tex live 2009, then the manager is no use at all (the only tl repos, now, are for 2011); so the only option is manual installation, as described in the README

Comment: I downloaded 2011 texlive package and installed and checked in the verse folder there is verse.sty file. when I run now I am getting this error " ! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \AtBeginEnvironment 
                                    
l.17 \AtBeginEnvironment
                        {Verse}{\singlespacing}
? " I have latest tex package on mac but I do not get this error, I tried to run the same at work in windows but I do not get this error. Just in ubuntu tex file fails to produce pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you installed TeX from the repositiories, look in the operating system package manager of the verse package in the comments to the packages. I list links to Debian packages, since Ubuntu uses Debian packages:

- [texlive-humanities](http://packages.debian.org/de/lenny/texlive-humanities)

  > **A collection of LaTeX packages for law, linguistics, the social sciences,**
  >    **and the humanities.**
  >
  > This package includes the following CTAN packages:
  >   ....
  >
  > verse -- Aids for typesetting simple verse.
- or [texlive-latex-extra](http://archive.debian.net/etch/texlive-latex-extra)

  > **A large collection of add-on packages for LaTeX.**
  >
  > This package includes the following CTAN packages: 
  >   ....
  >
  > verse -- Aids for typesetting simple verse.

Also `apt-search` can help, such as:

```
sudo apt-cache search verse | grep tex
```

You can install by Synaptic or another manager or on the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-humanities
```

Comment: This is what I am getting with your commands  texlive-humanities is already the newest version.
texlive-humanities set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
aku@aku-desktop:~$ sudo apt-cache search verse | grep tex
libhtml-format-perl - format HTML syntax trees into text, PostScript or RTF
texlive-latex-extra - TeX Live: LaTeX supplementary packages
tea - text editor with syntax highlighting & UTF support
texlive-humanities - TeX Live: Humanities packages
aku@aku-desktop:~$

Comment: As of Ubuntu 16.04 `verse` is only in `texlive-humanities`, not `texlive-latex-extra`.